# Как уменьшить видимый размер canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, canvas

У меня в  canvas `1000*1000` рисуется картинка, а потом сохраняется на компьютер.
canvas `1000*1000`  не красиво смотрится на экране, а если его уменьшить до `300*300` - сохраняемая картинка тоже становится меньше и качество очень падает.

Можно ли его как то уменьшить, но так чтобы сохраняемая картинка осталась `1000*1000`?

```js
function download() {
  var dt = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
  this.href = dt;
};
```

Comment: можно большой сделать невидимым и затем перерисовать его в маленький.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
canvas { outline: 1px dotted red; }
```

```html
<canvas width=1000 height=1000 style="width:300px; height:300px;"></canvas>
```